# Dynamically declare various 2D arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have to declare THREE 2D arrays in C size of Rx3 called array1,array2 and sum.

```
int main() 
{
  int row = 0;
  printf("Enter the no. of rows:");
  scanf("%d", &row);
  printf("MyArray[%d][3]", row);

  int ** array1;
  array1 = (int**)malloc(4 * row);
  int rep1;
  for (rep1 = 0; rep1 <= row; rep1++) 
  {
    array1[rep1] = (int*)malloc(3 * 4);
  }

  int ** array2;
  array2 = (int**)malloc(4 * row);
  int rep2;
  for(rep2 = 0; rep2 <= row; rep2++)
  {
    array2[rep2] = (int**)malloc(3 * 4);    
  }
}
```

but this code isn't working and how do i add the third array

Comment: Simple hint: never use 2D arrays in C, particularly for heap allocated data. Always use mono-dimensional arrays, perhaps as [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), and define your `static inline` functions to access and modify them to view them as matrixes. In other words, have your matrix abstract data type and implement it properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
array1 = (int**)malloc(4*row);
```

What is `4` here? is it `sizeof(int)` hardcoded or the number of columns?

To reserve space for a 2D array with a fixed width you can use:

```
#define COLS 4

int (*arr)[COLS]; /* A pointer to an array of n int's */
size_t nrows = user_input();

arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * nrows);
```

If you don't know the number of columns beforehand you can use a [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (since C99):

```
size_t ncols = user_input();    
int (*arr)[ncols]; /* VLA */
size_t nrows = user_input();

arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * nrows);
```

> How do i add the third array?

```
size_t ncols = user_input();    
int (*arr1)[ncols];
int (*arr2)[ncols];
int (*arr3)[ncols];
size_t nrows = user_input();

arr1 = malloc(sizeof(*arr1) * nrows);
arr2 = malloc(sizeof(*arr2) * nrows);
arr3 = malloc(sizeof(*arr3) * nrows);
```

Or if you prefer a big block:

```
size_t ncols = user_input();    
int (*arr)[ncols];
size_t nrows = user_input();

arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * nrows * 3);

int (*arr1)[ncols] = arr;
int (*arr2)[ncols] = arr + rows;
int (*arr3)[ncols] = arr + rows * 2;
```

In this way a simple `free(arr);` is enough.

Comment: 4 is the size of integer

Comment: Don't do that, always use `sizeof(int)`

Comment: And how do i add the both arrays?

Answer (score 0):

This code working fine in GCC compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        int row=0;
        printf("Enter the no. of rows:");
        scanf("%d", &row);

        printf("MyArray[%d][3]",row);
        int **array1 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);
        int rep1;

        for (rep1 = 0; rep1 <= row; rep1++)
        {
                array1[rep1] = (int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
        }

        int ** array2;

        array2 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);
        int rep2;

        for(rep2 = 0; rep2 <= row; rep2++)
        {
                array2[rep2] = (int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
        }
}
```